# Exchange Web Service issues - onsite mailboxes and offsite ones

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

Various parts of our system use Exchange Web Services to send internal emails and create calendar entries.

Historically, we have had a local exchange server hosting all mailboxes; however, we are currently in the process of migrating to a cloud-based exchange service.

My issue is that the code that has been working on the local exchange server doesn't work for the mailboxes we've moved to be hosted on the cloud (we moved a handful to test it before committing to the migration).

I think the crux of the issue is the `AutodiscoverUrl` call - this block finds the locally hosted mailboxes (obviously anonymised for security reasons):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

ExchangeService myExchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
{
    TraceEnabled = true,
    TraceEnablePrettyPrinting = true,
    TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All,
    TraceListener = labelTraceListener,
    Credentials = new WebCredentials(mySuperUser, mySUPassword),
    ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "MyEmailName") //The bit before the @
};
myExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl("MyEmailName@MyDomain", RedirectionCallback);
```

However, it looks like the `AutodiscoverUrl` call is being blocked with an Unauthorised response if I try switching the impersonation target to one of the mailboxes that has been migrated to the cloud. Considering that it works if I use the credentials directly associated with one of the remote mailboxes without doing the impersonation, I'm not too sure what the issue could be. I've managed to pinpoinmt a few possibilities - but I don't have access to the configuration of the exchange servers, so I'm reluctant to bounce the issue to the network administrator before I have a relatively conclusive idea in mind as to what the issue definitely is.

I'm thinking it's either a case of the superuser account being used for the impersonation not being present on the new cloud-based server, or there being a new setting that my googling hasn't returned?

Unless of course I've done something wrong in the code itself?

UPDATE: By appending the domain to the superuser (i.e. the full email address for it), I've got it finding all mailboxes - it simply lacks the ability to send anything from the cloud-hosted mailboxes.

The exception received is as follows:

```
There was a problem sending the email - please try again!<br />Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse() in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\EwsHttpWebRequest.cs:line 113
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 821
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 831
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 724
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute() in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\MultiResponseServiceRequest.cs:line 157
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line 401
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ServiceObjects\Items\Item.cs:line 198
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend(FolderId parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ServiceObjects\Items\EmailMessage.cs:line 143
   at Assets_Controls_EmailControlWrap.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in N:\Documents\Code\FIS_NewLibrary\Franklin Information System\Assets\Controls\EmailControlWrap.aspx.vb:line 369
```

Comment: Do you need to configure a proxy to get out of the network to the cloud?

Comment: There is a proxy in place, yes. But considering that the impersonation seems to be the bit causing the issue, I'm not sure the proxy makes a massive difference

Comment: By cloud do you mean Office365? Basic Authentication is now disabled by default in the cloud so you need to switch to using oAuth authentication anytime you try to access a Mailbox in the cloud.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth. If you want to test if its is oAuth have a look at using the ewseditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases

Answer (score 0):

Using this tool: https://aka.ms/PillarEXOBasicAuth we found the issue - while the UI said that Basic Auth was turned on, it wasn't in the back-end; turning it on properly resolved the issue.